# Azure Service Bus Connections

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-servicebus-queues

I have inherited an azure service bus solution - C#, Web Api with Singleton service implementing the queue. Running locally on my PC, I can publish a message to my Dev queue and see that event consumed by my service bus receiver. No problem.
In our staging environment however my receiver is not firing so my code never processes the messages. I found an instance where a different environment was pointing to the staging queue purely by luck which makes me think "what else is using this queue". We have no application logging (useless I know) of when events are published or consumed so I wondered, is there a way from within Azure to see either

1. What is consuming the events published to the queue, or
2. What is currently connected to the queue so I can validate each connection and make sure a dev in a far flung office isn't running test programs using the queue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create application insights instance
2. [Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#enable-application-insights-server-side-telemetry-visual-studio) your web app in azure to the created AI
3. after some time you will be able to see requests to other systems sent by your app (in [application map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map?tabs=net) you'll see fancy diagram of requests, in logs you can query requests to service bus)
4. Drop the AI instance if you don't need it anymore